# Losing information after converting from character to numeric

Tags: r, character, type-conversion, numeric

I am facing a problem in converting long (19-digits) characters to numeric. After conversion they are transformed in an unpredictable manner. Why does the number change after 10th position in the character?

```
options(scipen=100000, digits=22)
a = '9440006300200000000'
class(a) 
[1] "character"
nchar(a) 
[1] 19
a_numeric = as.numeric(a)
a_numeric 
[1] 9440006300199999488
class(a_numeric)
[1] "numeric"
nchar(a_numeric)
[1] 19
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: If  you want you can use bigint `library(gmp)
a_numeric=as.bigz(a)`

Comment: Thanks Batanichek, as.bigZ solves the problem.